# Controller logic for two different type of users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, controllers

In my project i have three different categories of users:

- `Guest`
- `Registered`
- `Admin`

If a `Registered` user is logged in, I want to show them (if they click on a button) their orders.

The `Admin` instead can see the orders of all the users. I can use `OrdersController` to show things to the `Registered` user.

Is it necessary to create a new controller for the `Admin` , or I can use a `if the user is a admin do this` clause in the same controller(say `OrdersController`) that I use for the `Registered` users?

Comment: You can do both. So?

Comment: Hi, thanck you for answering.what is the best practise? separete the logic or usa a single controller with if?

Comment: It depends on how different the behavior of orders is to the admin. If it's **really** different, a separate controller may be best. Otherwise, it may very well be a waste of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no single right answer to this question, it really depends a lot on your code, your app, your use cases, and a whole bunch of other detail that you haven't provided (and that this is not the best forum for).

So, generally the administration tasks are so distinct from the regular users that people create new controllers for them, usually under their own `Admin::` namespace.